# Problems with accents in using c++ and qt

Tags: qt, text, character-encoding, utf

I'm writing a program in spanish. I want to tell the user that a file has been loaded. In spanish that is:

```
ui->teLog->append("Se cargó el archivo: " + filename);
```

However the spanish parts gets outputted as:

> Se cargÃ³ el archivo:

I know the problem is the encoding (like I need to tell the program this is UTF8, I think).
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal QString constructor assumes you're writing ASCII characters. If you use `QString::fromUtf8()` in this case it should work:

```
ui->teLog->append(QString::fromUtf8("Se cargó el archivo: ") + filename);
```

Also:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings( QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8") );
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384227/in-qt-how-to-setcodecforcstrings-globally-in-header) for more info)

Comment: Thank you!, However one question is there any other solution so that I don't have to write that in every string.....

Comment: user792589: In Qt5: QStringLiteral(). It's good style to explicitly convert literals to QString anyway. Or use English in the source code and internationalize using tr(), then translate to Spanish. That keeps the encoding hell out of source files and works reliably with all compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider writing all messages in plain english using latin1 language and using Qt translations features for converting messages into spanish. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-translators.html

This has several advantages:

- your program will be translatable to other languages
- non-spanish
  developers will be able to modify your code more easily (assuming
  that every developer knows english and only some know spanish).