# Qt std::string to QString with special characters

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

I have Qt5 (5.7) and I'am facing a strange issue.
I was unable to transform a std::string (output of a tested algorithm) to QString by following simple methods.

Does anybody have an idea ?

here are simple examples I have tested (none of these lines work...). each time the Visual studio watcher gave me the unknow character for accentuated letters.

```
std::string l_s = "&é'(-è_çà)=";
QString l = QString::fromUtf8(l_s.data(), l_s.size());
QString lll = QString::fromStdString(l_s);

QByteArray l_ba = QString::fromStdString(l_s).toUtf8();

QString l_t = "&é'(-è_çà)=";
std::string res = l_t.toStdString(); // here I lost information

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QString ss = codec->toUnicode(l_s.c_str());
```

Comment: Something like this `&Ú'(-Þ_þÓ)=`? This solution may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531105/problems-with-accents-in-using-c-and-qt

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already test this soution without success. The string I have is stored in a std::string.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. In a Linux system. Using Qt 5.6.0:

```
#include <QString>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "&é(-è_çà)=";
    std::cout << "std::string: " << str << std::endl;

    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(str);
    std::cout << "QString: " << qstr.toStdString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
std::string: &é(-è_çà)=
QString: &é(-è_çà)=
```

Comment: Thank you. It works when the string is directly written in intialization but sometimes does not work when the string comes from the output of an algorithm.

Comment: @Joh can you provide a sample of the code using that algorithm?